# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) related vlc

Tags: vlc

I am new to the Linux world, so I did clean installation. However, when I am trying to install a new programs or even update I am coming across with a problem related to "vlc".
[So, I tried to remove it, but without any luck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i619.png)

Answer (score 0):

Purge the conflicting package:

```
sudo dpkg -P vlc-nox
```

then fix:

```
sudo apt install -f
```